# How do I change the default "Save File Location" in VVVVVV on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vvvvvv

Usually, VVVVVV saves the games in my Documents folder. How can I change this? I don't want my saved games appearing in my documents folder – I just don't know how to change the location without corrupting my progress.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE Andrew :)

Comment: Thanks Wipqozn. I've been creeping on these forums for a while, but I've never made an account.

Comment: Do you have the non-drm version or the Mac App Store version?

Comment: I have the non-DRM version. I bought it during the Humble Indie Bundle #3 launch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up just moving the saved file to a different folder when I don't want to play VVVVVV, and when I do want to play, I just move it back. There's no error that comes up, and no corruption of the file. It's just a simple drag and click. Not exactly a technical solution, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't. VVVVVV is a flash game that is "converted" to a mac app via something called Flash Projector. Since the entire game (including saving and reading files) is written in action script and translated through this projector interface, the game is probably using the [AS3 File APIs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) to write/read from a hardcoded location such as your documents directory.

It doesn't sound like you're willing to just symlink that directory elsewhere - you want it completely gone from your Documents folder. And that is something you can probably only do by convincing the developer to change the location and send you a custom build.

Hey, it's an indie game, anything is possible.

Comment: It's actually not a Flash game anymore. For update 2.0 (which was first released in the HIB #3), it was rewritten in C++. The old version used Flash LSOs, but those end up somewhere in `AppData` (or Mac equivalent), not `Documents`.

Comment: Whoops, I guess I have the old version then.

Comment: I ended up just moving the saved file to a different folder when I don't want to play, and when I do want to play, moving it back to its original spot. No biggy.

Comment: @Andrew If that's your answer, then that's **the** answer!

Comment: ...Sometimes the simplest solution is the best solution, huh?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you want to put a little work in and use the Terminal.

The first step requires moving it where you want it.

Next create a SymLink in place of the folder's original spot with its original name pointing to the new location. Open the Terminal.app in /Applications/Utilities and type:

```
cd ~/Documents/
ln -s /new/location/of/VVVVVV/folder VVVVVV
```

Then lastly simply make the SymLink hidden.

```
chflags hidden ~/Documents/VVVVVV
```

A tip with the Terminal is you can drag the proxy icon (The folder icon in the titlebar of a Finder window) into the Terminal and it will type out the path for you. So just type cd and drag the folder icon for Documents in, or type ln -s and drag the VVVVVV folder from its new location into the Terminal and it will save you time trying to type out the entire path.

If you're afraid of the Terminal, don't worry, nothing here is destructive.